# Same high in Bootstrap Cards with a Link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i want to link bootstrap cards in a form. It is important to me that no normal link is inserted there. The data should be sent together with other data via POST.

Unfortunately I now have a display problem. The blocks should all be the same height. Works even if I don't add a link. But as soon as I link them, it no longer works.

I once attached the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<title>KSS</title>

<!-- Einbindung der CSS Dateien -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!--Bootstrap 4.5.2 -->
<link href="css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!--Icon-Schriftart -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!--Benutzerdefinierter Style für die gesamte Website -->
<link href="css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!--Toogle/Switch Buttons -->

<!-- Einbindung von Javascribt Dateien -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script><!--jquery -->
<!--<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script><!--Bootstrap -->
<script src="js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script><!--Toogle/Switch Buttons -->

</head>

<body>



<div class="container-xl">




          <div class="row">
          
<div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex">
              <div class="card card-body flex-fill">
                <p>Die ist ein langer Text. Dies ist ein langer Text. Dies ist ein langer Text.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex">
              <div class="card card-body flex-fill">
                <p>Dies ist ein kurzer Text.</p>
                </div>
            </div>


          </div>
   
--------------------------------------
<form>
          <div class="row">

 <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex">
   <label><input type="submit" name="geraete-kategorie" class="card-input-element" value="<?=$row['id'] ?>"/>
              <div class="card card-body card-input flex-fill">
                <p>Die ist ein langer Text. Dies ist ein langer Text. Dies ist ein langer Text.</p>
                </div>
    </label>
            </div>
            
            
             <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex">
   <label><input type="submit" name="geraete-kategorie" class="card-input-element" value="<?=$row['id'] ?>"/>
              <div class="card card-body card-input flex-fill">
                <p>Dies ist ein kurzer Text.</p>
                </div>
    </label>
            </div>
            
            
             <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex">
   <label><input type="submit" name="geraete-kategorie" class="card-input-element" value="<?=$row['id'] ?>"/>
              <div class="card card-body card-input flex-fill">
                <p>Dies ist ein kurzer Text.</p>
                </div>
    </label>
            </div>


</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

You can see the site live:
http://felix.swissitup.com/test.html

What must I add in the css that the code works?

Comment: Add `height: 100%` to `.card-body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
label {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

use this it will definitely work